# QGIS Python Composer Attribute Table has no content

Tags: qgis, python, print-composer

I add to the composer an attribute table and in this table there is no content.

My Code:

```
    mapRenderer = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
    c = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
    c.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
    x, y = 0, 0
    w, h = c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight()
    composerMap = QgsComposerMap(c, x,y,w,h)
    c.addItem(composerMap)

    composerLabel = QgsComposerLabel(c)
    composerLabel.setText("Hello world")
    composerLabel.adjustSizeToText()
    c.addItem(composerLabel)

    tableGes = QgsComposerAttributeTable(c)
    tableGes.setVectorLayer(vlayer)
    tableGes.setComposerMap(composerMap)
    tableGes.setDisplayOnlyVisibleFeatures(True)
    c.addItem(tableGes)
    ## Here i try this Methode also:
    ##c.addComposerTable(tableGes)
    ## Same result!

    printer = QPrinter()
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName("E:\***\out.pdf")
    printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(c.paperWidth(), c.paperHeight()),
    QPrinter.Millimeter)
    printer.setFullPage(True)
    printer.setColorMode(QPrinter.Color)
    printer.setResolution(150)

    pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
    c.renderPage(pdfPainter, 0)
    pdfPainter.end()
```

Additional I post the out.pdf as a image.

[image]

Can someone try the code in their own plugin?

If there is the same result i can make a bug report.

If not, I need to search for the bug in my plugin.

Comment: Are you using QGIS stable (2.0) or Master/Dev (2.1)?

Comment: I try it in 2.0 and 2.1 ...

Comment: Is the CRS of the project and the layer the same / correct?

Comment: I check it ... yes it is the same crs ...

Comment: have you tried setting the projection of the map renderer? myMapRenderer.setProjectionsEnabled( True )
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
crs.createFromSrid( 32632 )
myMapRenderer.setDestinationCrs( crs )

Comment: I try it ... same result :(

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug and it is fixed upstream [f867506](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/f867506b8ef209c327176d58ec361a31a5602612) It will be part of QGIS 2.2 and 2.0.2